# Error Converting C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net, code-conversion

I am trying to convert this method to VB.NET but the online converters seem to make a mess of converting it. Can someone help:

C# original:

```cs
private IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Reference>> FindReferencesWithTheSameShortNameButDiffererntFullNames(List<Reference> references)
        {
            return from reference in references
                   group reference by reference.ReferencedAssembly.Name
                       into referenceGroup
                       where referenceGroup.ToList().Select(reference => reference.ReferencedAssembly.FullName).Distinct().Count() > 1
                       select referenceGroup;
        }
```

VB.NET Using online converter:

```vb
Private Function FindReferencesWithTheSameShortNameButDiffererntFullNames(references As List(Of Reference)) As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of String, Reference))
        Return _
            Where referenceGroup.ToList().[Select](Function(reference) reference.ReferencedAssembly.FullName).Distinct().Count() > 1
End Function
```

This errors on `Where` is not declared.

I wouldn't have thought that the VB would not be that dis similar to the C# something like this:

```vb
Private Function FindReferencesWithTheSameShortNameButDiffererntFullNames(references As List(Of Reference)) As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of String, Reference))
            Return From reference In references
                   Group reference By reference.ReferencedAssembly.Name
                   Into referenceGroup()
                   Where referenceGroup.ToList().Select(Function(reference) ReferencedAssembly.FullName).distinct().count() > 1
                                                        Select referenceGroup

        End Function
```

But I get: Definition of method referenceGroup is not accessible in this context...can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you attempted to look up the syntax of a group, into, where, select statement by yourself.  this would involve coverting the code by hand something you should do, doesn't seem you have attempted much beyond, what an automatic tool has given you.

Comment: @Ramhound - yes I have tried this myself - I originally posted the converted code so that I didn't get flippant comments saying 'use an online code converter!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.Net differs slightly in its syntax. The `Group` keyword also indicates the current grouping and can be used directly or assigned to a named variable.

```
 Private Function FindReferencesWithTheSameShortNameButDiffererntFullNames(references As List(Of Reference)) As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of String, Reference))
    Return From referenceGroup In references.GroupBy(Of String, Reference)(Function(reference) reference.ReferencedAssembly.Name, Function(reference) reference)
           Where (referenceGroup.ToList().Select(Function(reference) As String
                                                     Return reference.ReferencedAssembly.FullName
                                                 End Function).Distinct().Count() > 1)
           Select referenceGroup
End Function
```

**Update**

I just noticed you were returning an `IGrouping`. The query comprehension syntax won't work under that circumstance and you will have to make an explicit call to `GroupBy()`. The code example has been updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

The original C# code does some operations unnecessarily, so lets clean it up first and do some optimizations.

The `ToList()` call is unnecessary, remove it.  Calling `Count()` enumerates through all items to get the count but you only want to check if there's more than one.  It would be better to skip the first result and see if there is any more and would be logically equivalent.

```cs
private IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Reference>>
    FindReferencesWithTheSameShortNameButDiffererntFullNames(
        List<Reference> references)
{
    return
        from reference in references
        group reference by reference.ReferencedAssembly.Name into referenceGroup
        where referenceGroup
            .Select(reference => reference.ReferencedAssembly.FullName)
            .Distinct()
            .Skip(1)
            .Any()
        select referenceGroup;
}
```

So to translate this:

```vb
Private Function FindReferencesWithTheSameShortNameButDiffererntFullNames(references As List(Of Reference)) As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of String, Reference))
    Return
        From referenceGroup In references.GroupBy(Function(reference) reference.ReferencedAssembly.Name)
        Where referenceGroup.Select(Function(reference) reference.ReferencedAssembly.FullName).Distinct.Skip(1).Any
        Select referenceGroup
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff but unfortunately this does not compile (it errors on `Where referenceGroup`- I think it to do with what @ChrisHannon mentioned about the Group syntax

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure that construct works.  I'll have to look at that again when I get the chance when I get back home.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that VB does that.  So the explicit `GroupBy()` call is needed then... though I still think you should take the optimizations however.

Comment: I agree - I had already +1'd you for the explanation as this was very useful anyway

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as removing the brackets from referenceGroup? I'm wondering if vb thinks it's a method not an identifier.

Comment: Unfortunately not - the IDE adds them back in if you remove them from my example